# Route without page reload on bookmark or manual URL edit

Tags: ember.js

If I'm on a page in my Ember app, and edit the URL manually or use a bookmark that identifies another route within the same app, by default the page gets reloaded, losing any transient state it had, rather than just transitioning as it would have if I'd followed an Ember-controlled link within the app. Is there a built-in feature of Ember that's well integrated into its routing features which can prevent that and just transition instead?

Details:

With Ember's default routing, the URL itself changes rather than just the fragment identifier ("hash"). E.g., in the [Quick Start](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/getting-started/quick-start/) example, if you're on http://server/scientists and want to look at the list of programmers instead, you go to http://server/programmers.

If you do that by clicking a link handled by Ember, that works within the loaded page just fine (I'm assuming Ember uses the History API under the covers to replace state without page reload). No page reload is caused.

But if you're on http://server/scientists and click a bookmark to take you to http://server/programmers (or edit the URL manually), it reloads the page, losing any transient state the page contained.

In contrast, in an app that uses fragment identifiers for routing (like Gmail), the equivalent change of (say) http://server/#scientists to http://server/#programmers does not cause page reload, even if you manually edit the address bar or use a bookmark. (Of course; it's just a change to the fragment identifier, not the actual URL.)

Is there built-in handling in Ember that's well integrated into its routing features that can make it handle that use case without reloading? Either by using a fragment identifier instead of changing the URL, or with some History API feature? (Although I can't think of a History API feature that could do it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In config/environment.js file, include `ENV.locationType= 'hash';` by default it would be set to `auto`.
For more information -  http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html

Comment: Doesn't get more integrated with the built-in routing than that! Perfect, thanks.